# Move Xml Nodes Up / Down using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to re-order xmlnodes by comparing them with datatable rows. Below is my code and an example.

```
    <OrderDetails>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode1</StockCode>
    <StockDescription>Description1</StockDescription>
  </StockLine>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode2</StockCode>
    <StockDescription>Description2</StockDescription>        
  </StockLine>
  <CommentLine>        
    <Comment>Comment1</Comment>        
  </CommentLine>
  <CommentLine>       
    <Comment>Comment2</Comment>        
  </CommentLine>
</OrderDetails>
```

I am querying this against my data table to move comment node up/down. If the data table column "comment" has any value then add the comment node under the corresponding stockline node. If the data table column "comment" has no value then add next stockline node.

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(myxml);
 var stkline = from node in xmldoc.Descendants("StockLine")
                select node.DescendantNodes().ToList();
            var cmntline = from node in xmldoc.Descendants("CommentLine")
                select node.DescendantNodes().ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < DatatTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string dtstcode = DatatTable.Rows[i]["StockCode"].ToString();
                string dtstkdes = DatatTable.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();               
                string dtcmnt = DatatTable.Rows[i]["Comment"].ToString();
                foreach (List<XNode> el in stkline)
                {
                    XNode stckelement = el.FirstOrDefault();
                    XNode nextnode = stckelement.NextNode;

                    foreach (List<XNode> cmntnode in cmntline)
                    {
                        XNode cmnt = cmntnode.FirstOrDefault();

                        if (DatatTable.Rows[i]["Comment"] != null)
                        {
                            cmntnode.Remove();
                            nextnode.AddBeforeSelf(cmnt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(xmldoc.ToString());
```

Trying to acheive this outcome once the xml bas been organized

```
    <OrderDetails>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode1</StockCode>
    <StockDescription>Description1</StockDescription>
  </StockLine>
  <CommentLine>        
    <Comment>Comment1</Comment>        
  </CommentLine>
  <StockLine>        
    <StockCode>StockCode2</StockCode>
    <StockDescription>Description2</StockDescription>        
  </StockLine>      
  <CommentLine>       
    <Comment>Comment2</Comment>        
  </CommentLine>
</OrderDetails>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something simple like this.  I'm creating a list of Elements and then moving up or down based on the index number.

```
   class XmlMove
    {
        private List<XElement> elements { get; set; }
        private int index = -1;

        public XmlMove(XDocument doc, string elementName)
        {
            elements = doc.Descendants(elementName).ToList();
            index = 0;
        }
        public XElement GetNext()
        {
            if (index == -1 || index >= elements.Count - 1) return null;
            return elements[++index];
        }
        public XElement GetPrevious()
        {
            if (index <= 0 ) return null;
            return elements[--index];
        }
        public XElement GetCurrent()
        {
            if (index == -1) return null;
            return elements[index];
        }
    }
```